# Stopping loop when condition is met

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to loop through the whole array, and stop when my `if-condition` is met, then put the value in my var `checked`.

If the `if-condition` is not met,  the var should be set `false`.

When I put the `break` my script outputs `false`, which it shouldn't since `2002` exists in the array.

`subscriber = [2001, 2002, 2004]`

```
for(i = 0; i < subscriber.length; i++) {
  if (subscriber[i].ID == '2002') {
    checked = 'true';
    break; //added break here
  } else {
    checked = 'false';
  }
  Write(checked);
}
```

*(please don't mind the properties of the object e.g. ID)*

Comment: put the write OUTSIDE (after) the loop

Comment: "please don't mind the properties of the object e.g. ID" That seems to be the only problem with your code. If you change it to `subscriber[i] == 2002` it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `subscriber` array isn't formed correctly. Your `for` loop seems to indicate that each element in `subscriber` is an object with an `id` property.

Working off this assumption, you can optimize your code as follows:

```
const subscribers = [{ id: 2001 }, { id: 2002 }, { id: 2004 }];
const checked = subscribers.some(subscriber => subscriber.id === 2002);
```

The [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function will return `true` if anything in the array passes the check.